# Unable to find the floating point exception

Tags: c++

This code is showing floating point exception. I know why this error occurs, but I am not able to find the error in this code.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;
#define MAX 10005

vector<int> build_sieve() {
    bool arr[MAX];
    for(int i=2;i<=MAX-1;i++) {
        arr[i]=true;
    }

    arr[0]=false;
    arr[1]=false;
    for(int i=2;i*i<=MAX-1;i++) {
        if(arr[i]==true){
            for(int j=i*i;j<=MAX-1;j=j+i) {
                arr[j]=false;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<int>  v;
    for(int i=2;i<=MAX-1;i++) {
        if(arr[i]==true){
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    // int t;
    // cin>>t;
    vector<int> v =  build_sieve();
    cout<<"Prime no.s"<<endl;
    for(auto i = v.begin();i!=v.end();i++) {
        cout<<*i<<" ";
    }

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        int n,len;
        cin>>n>>len;
        ll arr[len];
        for(int i=0;i<=len-1;i++) {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        set<ll> s;
        for(int i=0;v[i]<=n&&i<=100001;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=len-1;j++) {
                if((arr[j]%v[i])==0) {
                    s.insert(v[i]);
                    cout<<v[i]<<" "<<arr[j]/v[i]<<endl;
                    s.insert(arr[j]/v[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<s.size()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say this code "has floating point exception" but I dont see float/double being used anywhere so I find that highly improbable. (Also variable names like s, n, t, v, arr make the code harder to understand than necessary)

Comment: `ll arr[len];` variable length arrays are a non-standard C++ extension (i.e. this code is not portable across compilers)

Comment: In this code n = input no, len = no. of intergers, I just have to find all the prime no.s which are less than n and which divide any of the len no. of intergers.

Comment: that is not the problem because for other programs , variable length array is working. I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTs

Comment: @KundanKumar Any chance that `v[i]` evaluates to `0` when you perform `if((arr[j]%v[i])==0)`? Tell us about the values you see when debugging your code.

Comment: Using VLAs are still a bad idea because you'll probably run into stack overflows when you work with larger arrays.

Comment: @KundanKumar - some compilers support VLAs as a non-standard extension in C++.   Even if it works for your compiler, using them is a really bad idea - they do not play well with other C++ features, they will not work with all C++ compilers, and the C++ standard library provides alternatives that work better in C++ than VLAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some systems report a floating point exception for an integer divide by zero.  So how can your code get one of those?  You divide by `v[i]` (the modulo operator `%` is a division).  How can `v[i]` be zero?  Because you're accessing past the ends of the `v` vector.

When you construct `v`, your list of primes, you only add numbers less than `MAX`, which is 10005.  However, in your for loop in `main`, you limit yourself to much larger indexes (`i <= 100001`), which is the *count* of primes, not the number that is prime.  Once you get past the end of `v`, you get into Undefined Behavior, which eventually results in the exception.